# Add shut-down/logout indicator to panel

Tags: icons, shutdown, panel, logout

I tried to remove the weather icon from the panel. I found an instruction on Ask Ubuntu (can't find it now) that I followed. The problem is that it also removed the "shut down"-icon, the power-indicator, the mail-indicator as well as the date-indicator.
How do I get these back?

Comment: If you use Unity: `unity --reset`

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime indicator-messages indicator-power indicator-session
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-datetime indicator-messages indicator-power indicator-session
```

or

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure indicator-datetime indicator-messages indicator-power indicator-session
```

If none of these solve it then please provide more information.

Comment: right click panel.
select add to panel.
select shutdown applet.
click add
select battery charge monitor
click add

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get back the shut down-button in a few seconds is this:

a right mouse click the task bar at the bottom, 2 options will appear, >preferences<, and >about<. Choose >preferences<, then >applets<, then the red circled >shut down<-button, and confirm. That's it! Next time you reboot the original button or buttons will all be there again, instead of the red one, which you can reinstall each time again whenever you should need it.

You will find the wheater icon there, too.